# Jquery global events and dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to trigger my own custom events as global events, so that anything on my page can listen to them and react, however, for dynamically added content it's not working. See my fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/6TMkG/8/

As far as I understand, the event is triggered for any element in the page that jQuery knows has a handler for it, and it seems it doesn't trigger the event for the `li`'s even though they do have a handler.

Anyone know how to get around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#b2").click(function() {
        //$.event.trigger("randomEvent");
        $('li').trigger('randomEvent');
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that does work, but what if I add more dynamic content that should be notified about the event that are not a li or above a li in the DOM. I then have to add another trigger on that item as well and what I would like is to have one trigger and anything ,irregardless of where it is located the DOM, that has a handler gets the event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want global event, then you could bind the event handler on document, and trigger it on any element in the document.

```
$(document).on('randomEvent', callback);

$('ul').click(function() {
  $(this).trigger("randomEvent");
});
```

Comment: How is that different from the handler I already have on the ul in my example that works? I want the event to be triggered for any content on the page that has a handler for it, in my example the li:s, which is supposed to be the way jquery handles global events but it doesn't seem to work so well with on/delegate/live.

Comment: @ErikNordenhök The point is you need to listen the event on document.

Comment: Do you mean something like my updated example or am I missunderstanding you? http://jsfiddle.net/6TMkG/11/
I suppose I could do something like that but for the code to make sense it feels like I want the handler bound to the element of the page that it does stuff to.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I completely missed that.. I did not see the first part of your question.. Custom events.. Looks like you are associating the randomEvent but you are not triggering that event when that is associated with it..

Make sure you add the trigger Event in the Document.Ready function so that the evnet handler is associated with as and when the element is available.